# Calling main() belonging to a package

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I could not understand this error, the scenario is:

This is the directory structure:

```
classes/
    root/
        pkgmain/Cmain.class
        pkg1/C1.class
        pkg2/C2.class
```

The problem is when I try to run Cmain file (main() is in this file) from the following path, I get the error:

```
C:\Ravi\MakingJarFile\classes\root\pkgmain>java Cmain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Cmain (wrong name: root/pkgmain/Cmain)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Cmain.  Program will exit.**
```

What could be the solution for this problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the *fully qualified* class name, and do it from the *root* directory (or put that directory in the classpath):

```
C:\Ravi\MakingJarFile\classes> java root.pkgmain.Cmain
```

or

```
C:\Anywhere> java -cp C:\Ravi\MakingJarFile\classes root.pkgmain.Cmain
```

You're telling the `java` command the full name of a class, and that's what it's looking for. When it finds a relevant class file it will check that the class within it really *does* have that fully-qualified name

Comment: do i always have to mention absolute path after -cp option. thanks for ur help

Comment: @RaviJain: No, it could be a relative path. For example, you can use `.` for the current directory. But you *do* always have to specify the fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full path to the class - otherwise java can't find the Class.

```
java root.pkgmain.Cmain
```